# concatenate char with int

Tags: c++, c

I have to concatenate char with int.
Here's my code:

```
int count = 100;
char* name = NULL;
sprintf((char *)name, "test_%d", count);
printf("%s\n", name);
```

Nothing printed. What's the problem?

Comment: You need to allocate some storage for `name`

Comment: Please specify which programming language you are using. C and C++ have *vastly* different idioms for solving this common problem.

Comment: @Rob: Is it not safe to assume that he would accept an answer which used idioms from either language?

Comment: @Dietrich, if you are going to be using C++ then use the C++ way. Same goes for C.

Comment: @Meng C and C++ are very different. Please learn which you are using and specify that one language alone in the tags. In this case it seems that you are using C because you would not use printf in C++.

Answer (score 6):

You didn't allocate any memory into which `sprintf` could copy its result. You might try:

```
int count = 100;
char name[20];
sprintf(name, "test_%d", count);
printf("%s\n", name);
```

Or even:

```
int count = 100;
char *name = malloc(20);
sprintf(name, "test_%d", count);
printf("%s\n", name);
```

Of course, if your only goal is the print the combined string, you can just do this:

```
printf("test_%d\n", 100);
```

Comment: The array doesn't need to be more than [17] on a 32 bit machine.

Comment: True. I must be lazier than @MooingDuck.

Answer (score 2):

If you programm C++ use sstream instead:

```
stringstream oss;
string str;
int count =100

oss << count;
str=oss.str();

cout << str;
```

Comment: You aren't checking that the stream operation succeeded.

Comment: can `stringstream << int` fail without throwing an exception?  (Not saying you shouldn't check anyway)

Answer (score 1):

You have to allocate memory for `name` first. In C, library functions like `sprintf` won't make it for you.

In fact, I am very surprised that you didn't get a segmentation fault.

A simple workaround would be using `char name[5+11+1]` for the case of 32-bit `int`.

Comment: The "heavy" library functions like `snprintf` tend to do a fair amount of error checking, as opposed to the "light" functions like `memcpy`.

Comment: @Dietrich: maybe you are right, but nevertheless it's strange. The [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) insists that _The size of the array passed as str should be enough to contain the entire formatted string_ and doesn't special-case NULL pointer.

Comment: `int` can be up to 11 digits: −2147483648 (on 32 bit)

Answer (score 0):

I use `boost::format` for this.

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>

int count = 100;
std::string name = boost::str( boost::format("test_%1%") % count );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the answer is tagged C++, this is probably how you should do it there:

The C++11 way: `std::string str = "Hello " + std::to_string(5);`

The Boost way: `std::string str = "Hello " + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(5);`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>  

int count = 100;

 std::stringstream ss;
 ss << "Helloworld";
 ss << " ";
 ss << count ;
 ss << std::endl;
 std::string str = ss.str();
 std::cout << str;

 const char * mystring = str.c_str();
```